# Volly JsonObjectRequest is not working and response is not getting called

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley

I have logged to understand the flow of code. And I also have tried to create an object separately and passing it to JsonObjectRequest. I am sharing function snippet. And also log result. I have tried to make request by using POST method as well. Still my response is not getting called. I have also tried to make an request by createing separate function but still it didn't work for me. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3i7F.png)

```
private void getWeatherInfo(String cityName) {
    String url = "http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=38c8359999e8407bbd7170418223007&q="+cityName+"&days=1&aqi=no&alerts=no";
    Log.d("Inside getWeatherInfo-", "API - "+url);
    cityName_textView.setText(cityName);
    Log.d("Inside getWeatherInfo-", "City name - "+cityName);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    Log.d("Inside getWeatherInfo-", String.valueOf(queue));

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("Inside JsonObjRqst--", String.valueOf(response));
            loadingPB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            homeRL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            weatherRVModelArrayList.clear();
            try {
                String temperature = response.getJSONObject("current").getString("temp_c");
                temperature_textView.setText(temperature + "°C");
                int isDay = response.getJSONObject("current").getInt("is_day");
                String condition = response.getJSONObject("current").getJSONObject("condition").getString("text");
                String conditionIcon = response.getJSONObject("current").getJSONObject("condition").getString("icon");
                Picasso.get().load("http:".concat(conditionIcon)).into(icon_imageView);
                weatherCondition_textView.setText(condition);

                if (isDay == 1) {
                    //morning
                    Picasso.get().load("https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/fluffy-clouds-windy-sky_23-2148824925.jpg?w=2000").into(background_imageView);
                } else {
                    //night
                    Picasso.get().load("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535418126925-0bfb3a0ee0d7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1yZWxhdGVkfDJ8fHxlbnwwfHx8fA%3D%3D&w=1000&q=80").into(background_imageView);
                }

                JSONObject forecastObj = response.getJSONObject("forecast");
                JSONObject forecast = forecastObj.getJSONArray("forecastday").getJSONObject(0);

                JSONArray hourArray = forecast.getJSONArray("hour");

                for(int i=0; i<hourArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject hour = hourArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String time = hour.getString("time");
                    String temper  = hour.getString("temp_c");
                    String img = hour.getJSONObject("condition").getString("icon");
                    String windSp = hour.getString("wind_kph");
                    weatherRVModelArrayList.add(new WeatherRVModel(time, temper, img, windSp));
                }

                weatherRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter Valid City Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

}

Comment: I am not able to replicate the problem - if I copy your code and strip out all the view-related stuff so it's just a pure JSON query it works fine - [example](https://pastebin.com/CX8frBrk).

Comment: As I mentioned api call is successful but I am not getting response for that. U can see there in code I have logged "inside jsonObject" that is not printed it means I didn't get the response. Check image that I have attached.

Comment: Yes, I reviewed it, and when I ran your the same query as you posted I got a response without an issue. Check the example code I posted and try running it. When I run that in a brand new project it works fine and returns the response. Is there some other error in the Logcat? Maybe a missing INTERNET permission in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I have defined INTERNET and location permissions. And there is no other error it is showing in logcat. It is showing "fail to call source". That to be not in error.

Comment: I also tried in new project but it wasn't working for me. And when I logging url in logcat. I am receiving all data but I m not getting response for that in layout.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am receiving all data but am not getting response for that in layout"? You ran the code I posted in a new project and see the JSON response is received in the log? The code I posted does nothing with a layout.